# What are the origins of ヶ?

Tags: kanji, history, etymology, kana, abbreviations

The ヶ in e.g. 一ヶ月 is a bit of an odd character - it looks a lot like a small version of the katakana ケ, but is it derived from that katakana originally? Or is it a normal kanji? Or is it something else entirely?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It has two main usages:

- As an abbreviation of the counter word 個/箇.

  - More often it has a further word after it and it's read か. In this case it's sometimes written as ヵ or even か so the reading is more obvious. Examples: 一ヶ月（いっかげつ）　二ヶ国語　三ヶ所
  - Sometimes it's used alone just like 個 is (and it's read こ too), perhaps as shorthand. I've rarely seen people do this, but then again I rarely see handwritten text, where shorthand would be handy. Example: １ヶ（いっこ）
- As something that roughly corresponds to the modern particle の in place names. In this case it's usually read が (especially in old Japanese the particle が has a close resemblance to the modern の). Examples: 西ヶ原（にしがはら） 鳩ヶ谷市

Place names will have some exceptions, as always, but I think these rules cover by far most cases.

Comment: I hate when a 地名 has this 'ga' in it, but the ヶ is not written with in the name.  Same with 'no'.

Comment: +1.  This is a way better answer than mine.

Comment: I wonder ヶ in place names is derived from 之. [真]{ま}[神]{かみ}[之]{が}[原]{はら}[尓]{に}, [瞿麦]{なでしこ}[之]{が}[花]{はな} as in [万葉]{まんよう}[集]{しゅう}.

Answer (score 9):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_ke):

> It is an abbreviation for the kanji 箇, which is used as a counter word. Although it resembles the katakana character ke (ケ), it is pronounced ka, ga or ko, not ke.

Answer (score 8):

It results from one of the components in 竹 , which is in turn taken from the radical sitting on the top of 箇 (a generic counter for pieces).

Answer (score 7):

Actually, it's a simplified version of any of the following: 箇・個・个

Comment: Note that the character [个](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B8%AA) is the simplified version of 個, and that the form 个 is very rare in Japanese.

Comment: Yes, but you can clearly see how ヶ is closer to 个 than the other ones.  In fact, I don't think I've ever seen 个 in any written Japanese.

Comment: Me either, except in a dictionary. :)

Comment: @Tsuyoshi Ito: I assume by "the simplified version" that you mean Simplified Chinese and not a Japanese simplification better known as "shinjitai"?

Comment: @hippietrail: Yes, I meant Simplified Chinese, not Shinjitai.  Sorry for the unclear explanation.