# Are the two kanjis 箇所 and 個所 interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice, usage, kanji, homophonic-kanji

Our customer uses 箇所 but my manager uses 個所 when emailing project status. Are both kanji interchangeable?

The context of usage in a sentence is:

> 一箇所変更しました。
>
> A portion (of the code/software) was changed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are the origins of ヶ?](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/347/what-are-the-origins-of-%e3%83%b6)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes they are interchangeable. They exist in these forms:

- 箇
- 個
- 个
- ヶ

Comment: is there a preference when to use which character?

Comment: @Nap. I do not know if there is a preference.

Comment: 个 is not usual in Japanese. In some cases it also shows up as ケ or カ or ヵ. They are not always interchangeable: see [Wikipedia](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%B5).

Comment: They are interchangeable when counting, but for example 危険箇所 is okay but 危険個所 is not, so they are not 100 percent interchangeable.