# Why is ケ here intead of か or カ?

Tags: translation

I was learning how to count months and the online video gave the expression in both hiragana and kanji.

Here is an example:

5 months

ごかげつ

5ケ月

Why is that ケ there ?

Should it not be ka ? As in か or カ ?

Comment: Did you make a mistake in writing the hiragana? ごがつ is ５月 (May). 5 months, ５ヶ月 (which is just one way to write it) is ごかげつ.

Comment: @Leebo Yes , I did indeed. I just noticed that your ''ke'' is a small ''ke''. Why is small ''ke'' in the kanji version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/347/9831 See also: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/36149/9831